# How to assert the width and height of an image in postman

Tags: postman

I'm attempting to assert the width and height of an image I am getting back from an api call.

The `Content-Type` is `image/png` and is just raw data from the api.

I am attempting to create an element and to place the png into it.

```
var img = document.createElement('IMG');
img.src = "data:image/png;base64," + responseBody;
console.log(img.naturalWidth);
console.log(img.naturalHeight);
```

However I am presented with the error:

```
ReferenceError | document is not defined
```

---

edit: The alternate approach suggested by a user here was the following:

```
const $ = cheerio.load('<img />');
var img = $("img");
img.src = "data:image/png;base64," + responseBody
```

However I am still unable to get the image size from this.

What is the recommended way to achieve this in postman?

Answer (score 0):

Use Postmans forums for help.Direct answer in this 
[thread](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3073#issuecomment-304051131).

Comment: That helps me get resolve the error but isn't really resolving my actual question.

Comment: You should extrapolate what is writtenthere.Cheerio lets you work directly wiht DOM files.Try looking here:https://www.codota.com/code/javascript/functions/cheerio/Cheerio/attr?snippet=5d4c7c317a552d0c0032d69d

Comment: As far as I've seen what you've linked does not work. When I print out the object that I've created with the code above it has no attributes or anything. Do I need to reload the DOM somehow after I make changes to the object's src as I have done above?